# preserving linebreaks in values in JSON key-value pairs

Tags: json, newline, line-breaks

I am not sure if line breaks are allowed in JSON values. I certainly am unable to create the following in JSON

```
{"foo": "I am not sure if line breaks are 
         allowed in JSON values. I certainly 
         am unable to create the following in JSON"}
```

The following certainly does not work

```
{"foo": "I am not sure if line breaks are\nallowed in JSON values. I certainly\nam unable to create the following in JSON"}
```

Preamble: I want to send a long message like above either to the browser or to the console app and display it neatly formatted so it is legible to the user.

Comment: See a similar [SO question answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

Comment: Have you been able to come up with a solution to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiline strings in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json)

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying (or inserting) the json value directly in HTML, you can't use it as it is because in html new lines are ignored and replaced by a space.

For example if you have:

```
<p>Hello,
I'm in other line.</p>
```

It will be represented as:

> Hello, I'm in other line.

You must convert the new lines to paragraph or `<br>`, for example:

```
<p>Hello,<br>
I'm in other line.</p>
```

That will be show as:

> Hello,
>
> I'm in other line

If this is your case, you can simply use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to change `\n` into `<br>\n`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're displaying it in HTML, 
 will simple do.
Or in a text area or something, try "\r\n", wrapped in double quotes.
Double backslashes are to escape.