# Can a JSON value contain a multiline string

Tags: json, multiline

I am writing a JSON file which would be read by a Java program. The fragment is as follows...

```
{
  "testCases" :
  {
    "case.1" :
    {
      "scenario" : "this the case 1.",
      "result" : "this is a very long line which is not easily readble.
                  so i would like to write it in multiple lines.
                  but, i do NOT require any new lines in the output.
                  I need to split the string value in this input file only.
                  such that I don't require to slide the horizontal scroll again and again while verifying the correctness of the statements.
                  the prev line, I have shown, without splitting just to give a feel of my problem"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: <code>  { "testCases" : { "case.1" : { "scenario" : "this the case 1.", "result" : "this is a very long line which is not easily readble. so i would like to write it in multiple lines. but, i do NOT require any new lines in the output. I need to split the string value in this input file only. such that I don't require to slide the horizontal scroll again and again while verifying the correctness of the statements. the prev line, I have shown, without splitting just to give a feel of my problem" } } }

}</code>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiline strings in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json)

Comment: I think this is more about readability of the serialized JSON file and _not_ about linebreaks in the loaded data (thus, not a duplicate of [Multiline strings in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2392766/703040)). Think of it more like using JSON as a configuration file where you have a long string and, for readability, it is helpful to hard-wrap the string in case someone is editing it via a text editor.

Comment: @zashu: Most text editors have a soft-wrap function. That's immediately more useful than some hard-coded line width.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit running git diffs (or resolving merge conflicts) on files with such long lines is also a pain.

Comment: This IS a dupe a of Multiline string in JSON, citing that OP's question: "*Is it possible to have multi-line strings in JSON? It's **mostly for visual comfort** so I suppose I can just turn word wrap on in my editor, but I'm just kinda curious...*"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are multi-line strings allowed in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/are-multi-line-strings-allowed-in-json)

Comment: not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42068/11107541. that question is about failure to properly escape the backslash of a newline escape sequence in a JS string literal containing JSON.

Answer (score 78):

Per [the specification](http://json.org/), the JSON grammar's *char* production can take the following values:

- *any-Unicode-character-except-`"`-or-`\`-or-control-character*
- `\"`
- `\\`
- `\/`
- `\b`
- `\f`
- `\n`
- `\r`
- `\t`
- `\u` *four-hex-digits*

Newlines are "control characters", so no, you may *not* have a literal newline within your string. However, you may encode it using whatever combination of `\n` and `\r` you require.

The [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) tool confirms that your JSON is invalid.

---

And, if you want to write newlines inside your JSON syntax without actually including newlines in the data, then you're doubly out of luck. While JSON is intended to be human-friendly to a degree, it is still *data* and you're trying to apply arbitrary formatting to that data. That is absolutely not what JSON is about.

Comment: "_While JSON is intended to be human-friendly to a degree, it is still data..._" There it is. Or, as [Crockford puts it](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), "_[JSON] is easy for humans to read and write. **It is easy for machines to parse and generate**._" [emph mine] One might argue that [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) would be a good addition, but one might have to argue with Crockford (and, natch, individual JSON implementations).

Answer (score 40):

I'm not sure of your exact requirement but one possible solution to improve 'readability' is to store it as an array.

```
{
  "testCases" :
  {
    "case.1" :
    {
      "scenario" : "this the case 1.",
      "result" : ["this is a very long line which is not easily readble.",
                  "so i would like to write it in multiple lines.",
                  "but, i do NOT require any new lines in the output."]
    }
  }
}

}
```

Then join it back as the need arrives with

```
    result.join(" ")
```

Comment: That's unsemantic though. It's an abstraction leak. I would consider a data format specified in this way to be, essentially, broken.

Comment: I can't imagine designing an API or JSON document this way just to increase string readability (only for debugging reasons I guess) :| ....

Comment: " I would consider a data format specified in this way to be, essentially, broken."

Consider that this is for a test case, though.  If you want to hard-code strings you probably want a properties file.  I personally wouldn't store "real" data in JSON in normal circumstances.  But if this is a simple way to go from no tests to tests, then go for it.

Comment: @AdamDyga in fact it could be usefull in order to store the json files into a CVS, where the unit of delta is the line.

Answer (score 9):

Not pretty good solution, but you can try the [**hjson** tool](https://hjson.github.io/). It allows you to write text multi-lined in editor and then converts it to the proper valid JSON format.

**Note:** it adds '\n' characters for the new lines, but you can simply delete them in any text editor with the "Replace all.." function.

Comment: That's a good idea actually. Version control the Hjson and have it transpiled to JSON as needed.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it depends on what json interpreter you're using... in plain javascript you could use line terminators

```
{
  "testCases" :
  {
    "case.1" :
    {
      "scenario" : "this the case 1.",
      "result" : "this is a very long line which is not easily readble. \
                  so i would like to write it in multiple lines. \
                  but, i do NOT require any new lines in the output."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but indentation spaces will output: `a\   c` => `a   c`.

Comment: JavaScript has no "JSON interpreter" that would accept this. It can only take JSON in a string. True, if you provided JSON inside a string literal then you could take this approach, but that's an unusual thing to do. Are you confusing JSON with actual object declarations in JavaScript?

Comment: This is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 3):

As I could understand the question is not about how pass a string with control symbols using `json` but how to store and restore json in file where you can split a string with editor control symbols.

If you want to store multiline string in a file then your file will not store the valid `json` object. But if you use your `json` files in your program only, then you can store the data as you wanted and remove all newlines from file manually each time you load it to your program and then pass to json parser.

Or, alternatively, which would be better, you can have your `json` data source files where you edit a sting as you want and then remove all new lines with some utility to the valid `json` file which your program will use.