# How I can add line to a json string without modifying its content?

Tags: json, indentation, readability

I want to make my JSON file more readable.
To do this I want to add a new line but without modifying any content.

For example, with this file :

```
   {
        "texte": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ?",
   }
```

I want to have something like :

```
   {
        "texte": 
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   }
```

Is it a way that I can do this ?
Thank you for your help,

Joss

Comment: It's not possible to do that :/

Comment: You can't do that; by definition, adding a new line or a line break would be modifying the content. It's impossible to not modify it if you're adding, removing or changing the content.

Comment: This was a solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690101/can-a-json-value-contain-a-multiline-string/21333578