# How do I get Insomnia to accept a string with newline breaks?

Tags: javascript, string, object, post, insomnia

So I have this string:

```
`JY1V03E          00000000009669170841620310325                                 
JYH4574108116GN17510704B0199182HCPP015326                                      
JYTA084A  0029900120200611                                      VJ7V21         
JYTE542A  0011880120200611356                                   VJ7            
JYTZ101A  0025860120200611                                      VJ7V21         
JYH5098919292BD19510816B0177895HCPP267910                                     K
JYTA084A  0028400120200713                                      VJ7V21         
JYTE542A  0011990120200713356                                   VJ7            
JYTG370A  0020640120200713                                      VJ7            
JY90000066000000000001190000000                                                `
```

And I need to pass it as part of a post request.  I'm using Insomnia, but it does not like new line breaks.

I'm hesitant to use things like: `%0D%0A` or `\n` as the purpose of all this is to pass this string to a parser to manipulate and altering the sting prior may be difficult.

The code is JavaScript.

How would I be able to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690101/can-a-json-value-contain-a-multiline-string