# Can there be a multiline key/value in json?

Tags: javascript, json, jsobject

Is somethhing like this possible in json

```
let a = {
    "awe
     sdsds" : "eweq
               dfs
               ewewew"
}
```

can i have multiline strings as key and value

I tried and got **↵** this icon at newline for key and **\n** this at newline for value

Comment: you could use yaml and convert it to json. otherwise (i didn’t test it) you may try to escape a line break with a backslash

Comment: No, it's not possible: control characters (linefeed in particular) are not permitted in JSON strings (https://www.json.org)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a JSON value contain a multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690101/can-a-json-value-contain-a-multiline-string)

Comment: This is not "JSON", it is object literal. Do you really have a JSON though? Also looks like https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not "JSON", it is object literal.

If you are having a literal you can use string literals and computed properties if you really want to have this kind of keys. Otherwise you'd need to use escape seq `\n` (see the result of `JSON.stringify`)

```js
let a = {
    [`awe
     sdsds`] : `eweq
               dfs
               ewewew`
}

console.log(a[`awe
     sdsds`])

console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
```