# PHP not outputting new lines from JSON data

Tags: php, html, json

I'm getting a feed that contains json data that is then decoded by php (json_decode) and echoed back out to my html page.

The feed contains `\n` characters but when the PHP echos them out, the HTML doesn't recognize them as new lines or line breaks so the HTML text just comes out as one big wall of text.

Can someone give me a hint as to what I should be doing to make the php echo out a 
 or something similar when the json data has `\n` in it?

As an example, the json data might contain "FRIDAY THROUGH WEDNESDAY.\n\nMORE RAIN IS" but when the HTML is generated it just looks like "FRIDAY THROUGH WEDNESDAY. MORE RAIN IS" all on the same line.

Thanks!

Comment: i don't think this is a problem with your json - how are you displaying it?

Comment: Wrap the echoed content in <pre> tags

Comment: probalby the duplicate of that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must replace your '\n' with the equivalent in HTML, which is the br tag.

You can output your string in the following way :

```
echo str_replace("\n", "<br />", $yourString);
```

Comment: The solution you posted prior to editing worked but I can't get it to work with nl2br.

Comment: Wierd, maybe it's your version of PHP? I put it back to how it originally was, for the sake of diversity.

Comment: Yeah maybe... do you know if nl2br works only when echoing? Because I have a bunch of echo statements that I didn't want to have to update I just tried changing the string like this:

$page = nl2br(file_get_contents('JSON_FEED_URL'));

Comment: It won't only work while echoing, but it won't modify the string you pass to it. It will return the resulting string, so you need to either echo or save the string that it returns.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my above response about the same time you replied to show that I am passing the string to nl2br. Would you expect that to work?

Comment: It might work, but I'd recommend putting the result of file_get_contents into another variable first. Especially if it gives unwanted results and you want to print the result to see what is in it.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo nl2br($json_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

From php.net:

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php#112084

```
function json_decode_nice($json, $assoc = TRUE){
    $json = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),"\\n",$json);
    $json = preg_replace('/([{,]+)(\s*)([^"]+?)\s*:/','$1"$3":',$json);
    $json = preg_replace('/(,)\s*}$/','}',$json);
    return json_decode($json,$assoc);
}
```