# Is there a bug in JSON.parse in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

Running Firefox 23.0.1, I have the following snippet:

```
var foo = '{  "success": false,  "errtype": "barf",  "message": "my message\n"}';

var what = JSON.parse(foo);
console.log(what);
```

Running this in the Firebug Javascript window, or watching the console log from my web page, I get SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal.

But this seems like valid JSON to me, per http://www.json.org/ and it also passes the validator here:  http://jsonlint.com/.

When I remove the "\n" embedded at the end of "my message", the problem in Firefox goes away.  Haven't tried other browsers.

Is this a bug in Firefox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle newlines in json?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

Comment: That `\n` might fall under the control character part of "any-Unicode-character-except-"-or-\-or-control-character". Keep in mind that by the time `JSON.parse` sees that `\n` it will have been converted to a single LF by JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to escape the backslash in the newline with another backslash

```
var foo = '{  "success": false,  "errtype": "barf",  "message": "my message\\n"}';
```

see [How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)