# Invalid control character with Python json.loads

Tags: python, json

Below is my string that is getting printed out with the below code -

```
jsonString = data.decode("utf-8")

print jsonString
```

And below is the string that got printed out on the console -

```
{"description":"Script to check testtbeat of TEST 1 server.", "script":"#!/bin/bash\nset -e\n\nCOUNT=60   #number of 10 second timeouts in 10 minutes\nSUM_SYNCS=0\nSUM_SYNCS_BEHIND=0\nHOSTNAME=$hostname      \n\nwhile [[ $COUNT -ge \"0\" ]]; do\n\necho $HOSTNAME\n\n#send the request, put response in variable\nDATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://$HOSTNAME:8080/heartbeat)\n\n#grep $DATA for syncs and syncs_behind\nSYNCS=$(echo $DATA | grep -oE 'num_syncs: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')\nSYNCS_BEHIND=$(echo $DATA | grep -oE 'num_syncs_behind: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')\n\necho $SYNCS\necho $SYNCS_BEHIND\n\n#verify conditionals\nif [[ $SYNCS -gt \"8\" && $SYNCS_BEHIND -eq \"0\" ]]; then exit 0; fi\n\n#decrement the counter\nlet COUNT-=1\n\n#wait another 10 seconds\nsleep 10\n\ndone\n"}
```

But when I load this out using python `json.loads` as shown below-

```
jStr = json.loads(jsonString)
```

I am getting this error -

```
ERROR Invalid control character at: line 1 column 202 (char 202)
```

I looked at char 202 but I have no idea why that is causing an issue? char 202 in my notepad++ is `e` I guess.. Or may be I am calculating it wrong

Any idea what is wrong? How do I find out which one is causing problem.

**UPDATE:-**

```
jsonString = {"description":"Script to check testtbeat of TIER 1 server.", "script":"#!/bin/bash\nset -e\n\nCOUNT=60   #number of 10 second timeouts in 10 minutes\nSUM_SYNCS=0\nSUM_SYNCS_BEHIND=0\nHOSTNAME=$hostname      \n\nwhile [[ $COUNT -ge \"0\" ]]; do\n\necho $HOSTNAME\n\n#send the request, put response in variable\nDATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://$HOSTNAME:8080/heartbeat)\n\n#grep $DATA for syncs and syncs_behind\nSYNCS=$(echo $DATA | grep -oE 'num_syncs: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')\nSYNCS_BEHIND=$(echo $DATA | grep -oE 'num_syncs_behind: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')\n\necho $SYNCS\necho $SYNCS_BEHIND\n\n#verify conditionals\nif [[ $SYNCS -gt \"8\" && $SYNCS_BEHIND -eq \"0\" ]]; then exit 0; fi\n\n#decrement the counter\nlet COUNT-=1\n\n#wait another 10 seconds\nsleep 10\n\ndone\n"}

print jsonString[202]
```

Below error I got -

```
KeyError: 202
```

Comment: Have you looked at character 202 yet?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: I looked at it but I have no idea why that is causing an issue? char 202 in my notepad++ is `e` I guess.. Or may be I am calculating it wrong

Comment: try `print jsonString[202]`

Comment: Do `jsonString = """{"description": ... }"""`.  Note that three double quotes (can be single as well) surrounding the braces.

Comment: After adding this, print jsonString[202] printed out `#`? But why?

Comment: There were no leading spaces in your original jsonString?  When I try your input, I get character 83.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

[There is no error in your json text.](http://ideone.com/sUFlEw)

You can get the error if you copy-paste the string into your Python source code as a string literal. In that case `\n` is interpreted as a single character (newline). You can fix it by using raw-string literals instead (`r''`, Use triple-quotes `r'''..'''` to avoid escaping `"'` quotes inside the string literal).

Comment: This answer is no different than mine.  Prefixing your string with 'r' (making it a string literal) escapes your newlines.  The problem lies with the OP's code.  If OP truly did `print jsonString` followed by `json.loads(jsonString)`, he wouldn't have encountered this error.  Otherwise, his console output would not have shown a literal \n but a newline.

Comment: @Pakman: incorrect. My answer: *"There is no error in your json text."*. Your answer: *"Escape your newlines."*

Comment: Your statement "There is no error in your json text" is correct, but there _was_ an error in the text he was inputting into json.loads, which we both address

Comment: yes. If you take a valid json string with `\n` in it and paste it into Python source code as a string literal then the string won't be a valid json no more

Comment: In case you don't have control over the JSON string, take a look at [Joe Cheng's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394235/invalid-control-character-with-python-json-loads#answer-29827074).

Comment: @RenatoByrro if you can't control a *literal* string in *your own* Python source code, you have bigger problems

Comment: @RenatoByrro if the string is not hardcoded then there is no issue with the json (read the very first sentence in the answer)

Comment: @RenatoByrro it would be a *different* question then. This answer addresses a case then a valid json text becomes invalid if copy-pasted as a Python literal string.

Comment: @RenatoByrro some people read past the title of the question but the question itself too. For those people, your comment may be misleading.

Answer (score 262):

The control character can be allowed inside a string as follows,

```
json_str = json.loads(jsonString, strict=False)
```

You can find this in the [docs for python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), or [the docs for python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

> If strict is false (`True` is the default), then control characters will be allowed inside strings. Control characters in this context are those with character codes in the 0–31 range, including `'\t'` (tab), `'\n'`, `'\r'` and `'\0'`.

Comment: This worked for me as I have no influence on how the json string was formatted.

Comment: Thanks @NikhilParmar You are a life saver :) I was struggling with this problem from last 3 days and finally this one worked for me

Comment: I used this solution as well, but then found that later, this caused a different JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string. Ideas how to deal with this?

Answer (score 17):

try to use "strict=False" in json.loads , it will ignore "\n" and another Control characters. like the follwing:

```
import json
  
test_string = ' { "key1" : "1015391654687" , "key2": "value2 \n " } '

res = json.loads(test_string, strict=False)
  
print(res)
```

output :

```
{'key1': '1015391654687', 'key2': 'value2 \n '}
```

Answer (score -3):

[Escape your newlines.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42073/116047)

```
{"description":"Script to check testtbeat of TEST 1 server.", "script":"#!/bin/bash\\nset -e\\n\\nCOUNT=60   #number of 10 second timeouts in 10 minutes\\nSUM_SYNCS=0\\nSUM_SYNCS_BEHIND=0\\nHOSTNAME=$hostname      #dc1dbx1145.dc1.host.com\\n\\nwhile [[ $COUNT -ge \\"0\\" ]]; do\\n\\necho $HOSTNAME\\n\\n#send the request, put response in variable\\nDATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://$HOSTNAME:8080/heartbeat)\\n\\n#grep $DATA for syncs and syncs_behind\\nSYNCS=$(echo $DATA | grep -oE 'num_syncs: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')\\nSYNCS_BEHIND=$(echo $DATA | grep -oE 'num_syncs_behind: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')\\n\\necho $SYNCS\\necho $SYNCS_BEHIND\\n\\n#verify conditionals\\nif [[ $SYNCS -gt \\"8\\" && $SYNCS_BEHIND -eq \\"0\\" ]]; then exit 0; fi\\n\\n#decrement the counter\\nlet COUNT-=1\\n\\n#wait another 10 seconds\\nsleep 10\\n\\ndone\\n"}
```

Works for me.

Also, if you get an error like this in the future, a debugging technique you can use is to shorten the string to something that works and slowly add data until it doesn't.

Comment: Then it should have complained before 202 character as well? Why it complained on 202 then?