# Python json.loads for utf-8

Tags: python, json, utf-8

I have a (not valid) json file, which is in UTF-8 format

The rough sketch of the json is:

```
{u'key': {u'key2': u'value'}, ...., u'key3' : u'value'}
```

Doing a simple python `json.loads()` results in the following error :

```
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Following some related answers on SO, I tried chanding it to unicode:

```
line = unicode(line,'utf-8')
data = json.loads(line)


ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

One solution I can think is to replace all single quotes by double quotes and proceed, but I was thinking - if there's an easier solution to parse the file to get python dict?

Comment: I would suggest you run your JSON data through a [JSON Validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) There's other kind you can google as well.

Comment: check if there are \r\n present in the source-string and ans by @joe-cheng [refer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29827074/4161807)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *NOT* JSON! It looks like a python serialization through `repr` which you can load with `ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)` from the `ast`-module.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` is much safer than `eval()`.