# The \r\n of textarea

Tags: java, html, json

A case of html as below:
1.`<input type="text">`, the input is "aa\r\nbb"
2.`<textarea></textarea>`, the input is "aa", "bb" and a newline between them.

Then I get the data from backend is both "aa\r\nbb"

But when I transfer it into JSON with some tools, the result is different.

`<input type="text">` ,the result is "aa\\r\\nbb",

but for textrea part, the result is still is "aa\r\nbb" .

So why isn't the "\" of textarea transfered to "\\"?

Comment: because entering \r\n in an input field is not the same as a line break.

Comment: Is it "a<cr><nl>b" in both cases or is it a string containing the backslashes?

Comment: somewhere during the translation to JSON, something is probably "escaping" special characters. it's common when you're dealing with a reduced character set. i'm not knowledgeable about JSON, so I can't provide a full answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle newlines in json?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)