# Python write valid json with newlines to file

Tags: python, json

Valid json expects escaped newline characters to be encoded as '\\n', with two backslashes. I have data that contains newline characters that I want to save to a file. Here's a simplified version:

```
data = {'mystring': 'Line 1\nLine 2'}
```

I can encode it with json.dumps():

```
import json
json_data = json.dumps(data)
json_data
# -> '{"mystring": "Line 1\\nLine 2"}'
```

When I print it, the newline displays as '\n', not '\\n' (which I find odd but I can live with):

```
print(json_data)
# -> {"mystring": "Line 1\nLine 2"}
```

However (here's the problem) when I output it to a file, the content of the file no longer contains valid json:

```
f = open('mydata.json', 'w')
f.write(json_data)
f.close()
```

If I open the file and read it, it contains this:

```
{"mystring": "Line 1\nLine 2"}
```

but I was hoping for this:

```
{"mystring": "Line 1\\nLine 2"}
```

Oddly (I think), if I read the file using python's open(), the json data is considered valid:

```
f = open('mydata.json', 'r')
json_data = f.read()
f.close()
json_data
# -> '{"mystring": "Line 1\\nLine 2"}'
```

... and it decodes OK:

```
json.loads(json_data)
# -> {u'mystring': u'Line 1\nLine 2'}
```

My question is *why is the data in the file not valid json*? If I need another - non Python - application to read it it would probably be incorrect. If I copy and paste the file contents and use json.loads() on it it fails:

```
import json
json.loads('{"mystring": "Line 1\nLine 2"}')
# -> ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 21 (char 20)
```

Can anybody explain if this is the expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just to explain: `the newline displays as '\n', not '\\n' (which I find odd but I can live with)`. That's because `\\ ` is the escape character for printing `\ ` itself. I'm not certain this is your problem but I suspect that in order to actually write two backslashes, you need to give python `\\\\n`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ran into the pitfall of neglecting the fact that the `\` character is also an escape sequence character in Python.  Try printing out the last example instead of calling `json.loads`:

```
>>> print('{"mystring": "Line 1\nLine 2"}')
{"mystring": "Line 1
Line 2"}
```

No way the above is valid JSON.  What if the `\` character is correctly encoded?

```
>>> print('{"mystring": "Line 1\\nLine 2"}')
{"mystring": "Line 1\nLine 2"}
```

Much better, you can then:

```
>>> json.loads('{"mystring": "Line 1\\nLine 2"}')
{'mystring': 'Line 1\nLine 2'}
```

Alternatively, if you really appreciate being able to copy some text from some other buffer and paste it into your live interpreter to do decode, you may consider using the `r`aw modifier for your string:

```
>>> print(r'{"mystring": "Line 1\nLine 2"}')
{"mystring": "Line 1\nLine 2"}
>>> json.loads(r'{"mystring": "Line 1\nLine 2"}')
{'mystring': 'Line 1\nLine 2'}
```

See that the `\` is no longer automatically escaping with the newline.

Also see: [How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json) and note how this is not a problem that exists strictly within Python.

Comment: The r'' raw string syntax will be really helpful. Thanks so much.

Comment: Out of interest, .encode('string-escape') also works, e.g.  json.loads('{"mystring": "Line 1\nLine2"}'.encode('string-escape'))

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this:

```
print(json_data)
# -> {"mystring": "Line 1\nLine 2"}
```

Is that `\\` is a valid escape sequence that ends up as a single backslash `\` when trying to print it.

The data in the json file is valid, as the parser is able to parse it :)

The confusion stems from the fact that when you try to print a string with escape sequences those get interpreted. And the sequence `\\n` is interpreted as `\n`