# jquery + json - \n not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I recently found out about .json files and I am trying to put a multiline string inside a data value, but it is just simply not working. I've tried \n and \r and \n\r but none work when they get put into my div from jquery.

Am I missing something here? This is my json file:

```
{
    "lText": "space\nbreak",
}
```

And here is my javascript:

```
$.getJSON("/js/content.json", function (data) {
    $(".lander .title").text(data.lTitle);
    $(".lander .subtitle").text(data.lSubtitle);
    $(".lander .text").text(data.lText);
});
```

Comment: hint: a HTML document uses HTML for formating

Comment: I know that, but putting a <br/> tag inside the json file just renders the br tag in the document.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed 1: "the document" referred to the web page document, and 2: you wanted `"space\nbreak"` to display as two lines in the document

Comment: If you want help you should post some code to show what you are doing with this type of data now, that way your errors can be pointed out for you

Comment: I edited my post trying to get more clear as I saw it getting downvotes. Sorry, should be easier to understand now.

Comment: Whitespace is ignored by browsers. If you want newlines, you have to do it with HTML markup (or put the content in a `<pre>` tag).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pre-emptive answer

```
div.innerHTML = s.split('\n').join('<br />');
```

but if you insist on jQuery

```
$.getJSON("/js/content.json", function (data) {
    $(".lander .title").text(data.lTitle);
    $(".lander .subtitle").text(data.lSubtitle);
    $(".lander .text").html(data.lText.split('\n').join('<br />'));
});
```

Comment: You can't use `.text()` to inject HTML content. You have to use `.html()`.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen did you change that last line to use `.html()` as in the answer? If you use `.text()`, it won't work.

Comment: I seem to have missed the '.html()' bit there, sorry.

Comment: FYI, if this is seriously what you were after, @SebastianOlsen, I've got 2 quick points. 1 - Just put the `<br>` in your JSON file to begin with. 2 - You are not trying to put a multiline string into a JSON file, you are trying to put HTML into a JSON file. Big difference - browsers will render HTML when added properly, but they will ignore whitespace for display. 3 - Make sure your usage of  `<br />` as opposed to `<br>` is appropriate. The former is for XHTML where self-closing tags are allowed and required. It won't break something like HTML5 per se, but it's bad form and not 100% proper.

Comment: @jimcavoli - have to disagree on your first point. Splitting on `\n` is trivial, and having the `raw` data could be useful for other purposes

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the "\" character for the newline like so:

```
{
    "lText": "space\\nbreak",
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42073/1728884

Comment: This just displays the \n tag inside my div.

Comment: Could you provide some more code then about how you're dealing with this JSON then in the page? I have a sneaking suspicion it's not being parsed into an object correctly.

Comment: The problem is that he's just setting `.text()` - newlines are just whitespace.

Comment: @Pointy you can add an actual newline, as in a `\n` through `.text()` since it's well...text

Comment: @jimcavoli yes you can, but the browser won't treat it as a line break unless the container has the right CSS rule

Comment: @Pointy And what CSS rule is it that will render a newline as a visible line break in-browser?

Comment: @jimcavoli I think `white-space: pre` would do it. I'd have to try it out to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$.getJSON("/js/content.json", function (data) {
    $(".lander .title").html(data.lTitle);
    $(".lander .subtitle").html(data.lSubtitle);
    $(".lander .text").html(data.lText);
});
```

And change `\n` to `<br/>`