# JSON.parse fails on space inside array

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, whitespace

I have saved this string in javascript

```
js_str= '{"id":"1","user_id":"1","cat_id":"1","name_bz":"Chitwan National Park","name_cf":"Gokarna","cf_lattitude":"27.525","cf_longitude":"87.56","boundry":"[[27.0656,85.255],[27.3564, 85.3564],[27.98998, 85.6898]]\n","area":"989.948","forest_conditon":"Poor","natural_regeneration":"High","grazing_pressure":"Medium","forest_type":"Natural","wild_species_list":"Tiger, Leopard, Rhino","others":null}';
```

On using `js_arr=JSON.parse(js_str)` it gives

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 207 of the JSON data
```

column 207 is the space after comma `[27.3564, 85.3564]`. The whitespace in this place is giving error. i cannot use regex to remove whitespace as it would replace all whitespaces.

Comment: Column 207 is the space. What could be the control character.

Comment: How are you getting the JSON string from server? Add that code also.

Answer (score 4):

There is a \n in the wrong place or should be escaped. Try to change from:

```
"boundry":"[[27.0656,85.255],[27.3564, 85.3564],[27.98998, 85.6898]]\n"
```

to:

```
"boundry":"[[27.0656,85.255],[27.3564, 85.3564],[27.98998, 85.6898]]"
```

or escape it to:

```
"boundry":"[[27.0656,85.255],[27.3564, 85.3564],[27.98998, 85.6898]]\\n"
```

Comment: That is not the problem. That character there is valid JSON.

Comment: I think the \n should be removed or escaped

Comment: the new line char needs to be escaped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json

Answer (score 4):

Just add a `\` before `\n` control character and all will be fine. JSON parser works like this.

```
js_str= '{"id":"1","user_id":"1","cat_id":"1","name_bz":"Chitwan National Park","name_cf":"Gokarna","cf_lattitude":"27.525","cf_longitude":"87.56","boundry":"[[27.0656,85.255],[27.3564, 85.3564],[27.98998, 85.6898]]\\n","area":"989.948","forest_conditon":"Poor","natural_regeneration":"High","grazing_pressure":"Medium","forest_type":"Natural","wild_species_list":"Tiger, Leopard, Rhino","others":null}';

JSON.parse(js_str)
```

**Successfully tested code in Mozilla Firefox.**
[image]

Comment: the \n is coming as a string from database . I cannot change it. Is there another way.