# Why does json_encode of a whitespace string adding it in an array?

Tags: php, json, simplexml

I've stubmled across this behavior on PHP 5.6 (also identical in PHP 5.4 up to 7.0).

```
$note = new SimpleXMLElement('<Note></Note>');
$note->addChild("string0", 'just a string');
$note->addChild("string1", "abc\n\n\n");
$note->addChild("string2", "\tdef");
$note->addChild("string3", "\n\n\n");
$note->addChild("string4", "\t\n");

$json = json_encode($note, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

print($json);
```

Outputs:

```
{
    "string0": "just a string",
    "string1": "abc\n\n\n",
    "string2": "\tdef",
    "string3": {
        "0": "\n\n\n"
    },
    "string4": {
        "0": "\t\n"
    }
}
```

There must be a reason behind this behavior, I would like to understand. And also, if you know of a way to force it to behave the same way for strings of texts and whitespace I would appreciate you sharing your ideas!

Edit. Here's a snippet you can run: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d797623553c11b7a7648340880a92e98b19d1925

Comment: I can't reproduce this running php 5.5.9. for me, string3 and string4 are just blank whitespace. however, curiously enough, the whitespace characters are being taken literal the same as your example for string1 and string2.

Comment: Added the snipped in my question.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII you are right on 5.5, but most of 5.6 versions are producing the above result. And all versions of PHP 7 I could test.

Comment: I see, your question does say *"also identical in PHP **5.4 up to** 7.0"*

Comment: If I don't use the `SimpleXMLElement` class, then I do get the same results when using an array instead `$note = [
  "string0" => 'just a string',
  "string1" => "abc\n\n\n",
  "string2" => "\tdef",
  "string3" => "\n\n\n",
  "string4" => "\t\n"
];`

Comment: Actually, all versions of `json_encode` do it this way. May have to check the EOL versions box, but going back to 5.2 (where it was introduced) they all act the same https://3v4l.org/IfBKK

Comment: I did try a few of each dot release and noticed the same behavior. However, many 5.5 release do not behave the same.

Comment: What is the expected output? I recon you're wondering where does `"0"` node come from.

Comment: Directly JSON encoding an XML document is always going to be tricky, because there's not a trivial mapping for every possible structure. And SimpleXML really isn't designed for that task, so isn't going to have considered all the edge cases. That doesn't exactly answer why it gives that output though.

Answer (score 1):

This comes from [RFC 4627](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4627.html) (emphasis mine)

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks **except for the characters that must be escaped**: quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the **control characters (U+0000 through U+001F)**.

Newline(`\n`) is `U+000A` in UTF-8 so PHP dutifully converts it back to its respective JS equivalent

PHP uses this RFC for [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

> PHP implements a superset of JSON as specified in the original » RFC 4627 - it will also encode and decode scalar types and NULL.

As I noted in the comments, all versions of PHP, going back to 5.2, do it this way([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IfBKK))

Comment: strange that this causes [decoding problems for others](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42068/4233593) when unescaped as `\n` instead of `\\n`

Comment: I might not understand it, but how does this character encoding ends up in {"0": "\n\n\n"} form instead of "string" ?

Comment: @Vallieres I think that's due to the SimpleXML conversion. If you put it into an array like I did it doesn't do that. I shoved the SXML back in for kicks and reran it and got all sorts of wackiness https://3v4l.org/kKfrL

Comment: Yes, exactly my problem. :( You're explanation is interesting but I'm wondering about the reasoning between SimpleXML -> JSON and possibly a way to fix this (without preg_replace'ng, of course).

Comment: The root of that problem is probably due to the fact that SXML is an object that contains other objects (and sometimes arrays). So if you have something come along and try to iterate it you get some really weird results. So I'm not surprised it grabbed an internal array and added it in.

Comment: @Machavity Actually, it's kind of the opposite: the SimpleXML object *doesn't* contain other objects and arrays, it just produces them on demand. The actual representation internally is native to libxml2 and not like anything PHP knows about.