# Getting attribute value using Ansible filters

Tags: python, json, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to get my attribute value from JSON data.

Here is my JSON data:

```
{
   "user1": "{\n \"data\":[\n    {\n     \"secure\": [\n       {\n              \"key\": \"-----BEGIN  KEY-----\nMIIEowIBAAKCAQEAgOh+Afb0oQEnvHifHuzBwhCP3\n-----END KEY-----\"\n       }\n      ],\n     \"owner\": \"shallake\",\n     \"position\": \"gl\"\n    }\n   ]\n}"
}
```

Initially, I had invalid JSON data, so I converted it into valid JSON using `to_json` and `from_json`. The above JSON data is the result that I get.

code:

```
 - set_fact:
      user: "{{ lookup('file','filepath/myfile.json') | to_json }}"

 - set_fact:
      user1: "{{ user | from_json}}"

 - set_fact:
      user3: "{{ item }}"
   with_items: "{{ user1['data'] | map(attribute='position') | list }}"
```

In a third `set_fact`, I am trying to get position attribute value. But it shows an error like this:

> the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'item' is undefined
>
> "\"{\n \\"data\\":[\n    {\n     \\"secure\\": [\n       {\n         \\"key\\": \\"-----BEGINPRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEowIBAAKCAQEAgOh+Afb0oQEnvHifHuzBwl+Tiu8LXoJXb/ii/eh\ngYEP3\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\"\n       }\n      ],\n     \\"owner\\": \\"shalloke\\",\n     \\"position\\": \\"gl\\"\n    }\n   ]\n}\n\n\""

So how can I get a position value from the above JSON data result using Ansible loop?

Comment: its a result which i got from my code set_fact: user1: "{{ user | from_json }}" and iam try to get the "position" attribute value from the resultant of json data.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please check if the key in `filepath/myfile.json` spans multiple lines? We need to escape line breaks in JSON. Use `\n` to replace line breaks.

The `user1` is supported to be a map parsed from JSON. However, the JSON in `filepath/myfile.json` might be invalid. So in the second `set_fact`, this invalid JSON couldn't be parsed. Thus, `user1` is just a string. And it doesn't contain an entry `data`.

```
{
  "data":[
      {
      "secure": [
        {
                "key": "-----BEGIN  KEY-----\nMIIEowIBAAKCAQEAgOh+Afb0oQEnvHifHuzBwhCP3\n-----END KEY-----"
        }
        ],
      "owner": "shallake",
      "position": "gl"
      }
    ]
}
```

[How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

Comment: I have tried that,now i convert my data as like this "\"{\\n \\\"data\\\":[\\n    {\\n     \\\"secure\\\": [\\n       {\\n         \\\"key\\\": \\\"-----BEGINPRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIEowIBAAKCAQEAgOh+Afb0oQEnvHifHuzBwl+Tiu8LXoJXb/ii/eh\\ngYEP3\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\\"\\n       }\\n      ],\\n     \\\"owner\\\": \\\"shalloke\\\",\\n     \\\"position\\\": \\\"gl\\\"\\n    }\\n   ]\\n}\\n\\n\""  .I have checked ,its in a proper json format and type as dict.But how can i get  "position" value from this item.I used with_items and get this as item in result.How can i get position valuein ansible

Comment: @jake I am not sure what you want. You can get a list of position via `"{{ user2['data'] | map(attribute='position') | list }}"`.

Comment: I have given like this to get "position" attribute alone.But it shows like this  FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an               invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'data'\

Comment: HoW tohandle USING ANSIBLE not with python Invalid control character at: line 6 column 61 (char 110) in ansible this error,Since i have space in my secure key values of json data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use either `from_json` (not `to_json`) filter, or not use filter at all, when importing file in a JSON format into an Ansible dictionary.

I point out the mistake below, but first a working example:

- `myfile.json`:

  ```
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "secure": [
          {
            "key": "-----BEGIN  KEY-----\nMIIEowIBAAKCAQEAgOh+Afb0oQEnvHifHuzBwhCP3\n-----END KEY-----"
          }
        ],
        "owner": "shallake",
        "position": "gl"
      }
    ]
  }
  ```
- Playbook:

  ```
  ---
  - hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: no
    connection: local
    tasks:
      - set_fact:
          data_from_json: "{{ lookup('file','./myfile.json') | from_json }}"

      - set_fact:
          position: "{{ item }}"
        with_items: "{{ data_from_json['data'] | map(attribute='position') | list }}"

      - name: Display extracted position
        debug:
          var: position
  ```
- The result (relevant task only):

  ```
  TASK [Display extracted position] *********************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "position": "gl"
  }
  ```

---

Now your mistake:

Your `myfile.json` is not a correct JSON file.

You seemingly looked at the log of Ansible and copied it from the screen to the file. As you already saw, it will not be a valid JSON format (it will contain escaped quotes and newline characters which will prevent importing it).

If you want to copy the Ansible dictionary into a file, you can do it using the following task (I'm assuming here data is in the `data_from_json` variable, like at the end of my example playbook above):

```
- local_action: copy content={{ data_from_json | to_nice_json }} dest=./myfile2.json
```

`to_nice_json` is optional here, but it will produce very similar to the output as the `myfile.json` above (the order of keys might change and the indentation).