# php json_encode creating unescaped new line operators

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Here is my php:

```
$response = array(
    'errors' => $this->errors,
    'orders_fulfilled' => $this->orders_fulfilled,
);
echo '<pre>$response: ' . print_r($response, true) . '</pre>';

$json = json_encode($response, JSON_HEX_APOS);
echo '<pre>$json: ' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';
```

This shows the following output:

> ```
> $response: Array
> (
>     [errors] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => Error text
>
>         )
>
>     [orders_fulfilled] => 0
> )
>
> $json: {"errors":["Error text\n"],"orders_fulfilled":0}
> ```

**QUESTION:**

Why does php's `json_encode()` create unescaped `\n` characters out of actual newlines in the source php array, when they are not valid in the json string?

[I see in this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42073/2429318) the suggestion is to escape the source newlines, i.e. convert from `\n` to `\\n`. So why should PHP's `json_encode()` not be doing so here? As it stands it is directly creating a json string that chokes `JSON.Parse()` in javascript. For instance, try running this in console:

`JSON.parse('{"errors":["Error text\n"],"orders_fulfilled":0}');`

> VM1628:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position
>   22
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at :1:6

If I add a slash to escape the newline or remove it altogether, the error is gone.

Is there a flag for `json_encode()` that I should be using to handle escaping of special/control characters this that I have not seen in the PHP manual?

Comment: This is not a Shopify issue, strictly a question about php's `json_encode` and usage in conjunction with `JSON.parse`

Comment: Question do you parse the `$json` in the html (`print $json`)? Because then the linebreak is noticed by the browser! Or how do you test the `JSON.parse('{"errors":["Sh` line ?

Comment: If you can't control outputs of error, just add `addslashes` manually in your `$response`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of `json_encode` is fine.

The problem is that when you try to convert it to a JavaScript string literal by wrapping it with `'`, the `\n` gets parsed as a new line *in the JS string*.

When you try to parse that string as JSON, it has a real new line in it.

To convert to a JavaScript string, you also have to escape any special characters in it.

Since JSON is (more-or-less) a subset of JavaScript, `json_encode` will do that:

```
var json = <?php json_encode(json_encode($foo)); ?>;
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj);
```

… but that's a silly approach.

Just skip the bit where you treat it as JSON and just treat it as JavaScript.

```
var obj = <?php json_encode($foo); ?>;
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: ah I see, so this is being seen as an actual line-break appearing in the middle of a json value thus causing an "unterminated string literal" error?

Comment: I have since managed to verify that indeed the `\n` is perfectly valid within the json string literal

Comment: `\n` is valid in a JavaScript string. `\n` is valid in a JSON string. A `\n` in the expression of a JSON string as a JavaScript string will put a new line in the JSON string. A new line is not valid in a JSON string. To see this run `'{"errors":["Error text\n"],"orders_fulfilled":0}'` directly in your browser's JS console. Then copy the result, including the line break, into JSON Lint.

Comment: perfect demo of the problem right there! I am primarily a PHP head and my brain is thus used to only seeing strings in double quotes interpret the `\n`, whereas in single quotes the `\n` is taken literally. I didn't realise that a JavaScript string would interpret the `\n` as a literal new line (like in a PHP double quoted string), hence the flaw in my understanding.