# How to add new line in json format using c#

Tags: c#, json, newline, line-breaks

I am getting data from database using c#

```
subscriptionDetailInfo.SubscriptionDescription = item.SubscriptionDescription
```

output will be json as below

```
"SubscriptionDescription":"Before you can. begin to determine what. the composition of. a particular",
```

now i need to replace "." to new line.

My required output will be like this

```
"SubscriptionDescription":"Before you can
 begin to determine what
 the composition of
 a particular",
```

I try with following method but not working

```
 subscriptionDetailInfo.SubscriptionDescription = item.SubscriptionDescription.Replace(".", "/\n / g").Replace("/\n / g", "\\n")
```

output of the result as below

```
"SubscriptionDescription":"Before you can\\n begin to determine what\\n the composition of\\n a particular",
```

Comment: The result is correct. What you expect doesn't make sense. JSON is not a format for visualization.

Comment: If there is any way available to achieve this.... @HristoYankov

Comment: Are you viewing this in debugger? The debugger will show "\\n" as it escapes characters automatically, if you output your result to a file it would show as "\n".

Comment: @Equalsk It return below result `SubscriptionDescription":"Before you can\\n\\r begin to determine what\\n\\r the composition of\\n\\r a particular`

Comment: @equalsk i am checking in browser  and postman itself

Comment: It's showing you the escaped string, the same as the debugger.

Comment: Why do you care how it will show in the browsers? It is up to the consumer of that JSON to interpret the \n. A browsers is not the end consumer of a JSON format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42073/253266

Comment: @HristoYankov consumer receive that value in angular as string so he unable to do anything. he need to show that point one by one based on "."

Comment: @HristoYankov your link i already checked not working

Comment: The consumer could split on '\n' instead of '.'