# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog (JSON)

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have a string object that contains XML (including body and metadata).
When I try to parse it I get the following error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog

I tried to use `My_XML.getBody()` function but it didn't help.
I need some help with how to edit my XML so it will be allowed.

### Example XML

```
{"body": <<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TccSubscriptionData xmlns="tcc.generated.com">
    <MessageKey>
        <MessageKey>12</MessageKey>
        <Receiver>asd</Receiver>
        <Timestamp>2018-06-20T14:33:22.968+02:00</Timestamp>
        <ResponseType>sdf</ResponseType>
        <CorrelationId>0</CorrelationId>
    </MessageKey>
</TccSubscriptionData>
, "metadata": {"field1": "aaa", "field2": 123, "field3": aaa, "field4": "aaa", "field5": 123, "field6": {"field7":"aaa","field8":"a12d","field9":"aaa"}}}
```

Comment: If you are trying to parse the exact content as you posted, `{"body": <` is a prolog that is not XML compatible, and neither is the `, "metadata"...` stuff at the end. An XML parser can parse only XML, not a combination of JSON and XML.

Answer (score 0):

**Your example XML is embedded within JSON, and your JSON is not [well-formed](https://www.json.org/).**

In order to represent your XML as a string, you'll have to surround it with `"`, and you'll have to replace the `"` characters used as XML markup with `'` characters or escape them as `\"`.  You'll also have to remove the line breaks or [replace them with `\\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42068/290085).

Then, of course, as [M. le Rutte comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009852/xml-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-string-object-java#comment89012509_51009852), be sure that you're providing the XML parser with the XML extracted from the JSON, not the JSON message itself.