# How to handle new line for matTooltip?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, tooltip

I am trying to add new lines from a text area, but when I send the data to the API in json format folowing is the format.

```
{
   day: "2018-07-30"
   notes: "Enter↵New↵Lines↵in↵Textarea↵"
   time: "4"
}
```

as you can see in the given object "notes" property has a special character added for enter.
How to handle this json format and again populate it to matTooltip with new lines.

**Expected output:**

```
Enter
New
Lines 
in
Textarea
```

**Current Output:**
Enter↵New↵Lines↵in↵Textarea↵

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

Comment: Hi @TimMartens that example doesn't solves my problem. I have already tried that approach.

Comment: how about replacing the charater `↵` by a `CRLF/LF` character using [string.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) when you `GET` the datas ?