# PHP 7.2 json_decode()

Tags: php, json, php-5.6, php-7.2

I have this string that was working with **json_decode()** with **PHP 5.6** but doesn't work with **PHP 7.2**?

```
$json = '
{
  "text": "Hi {{fname}} 
   Welcome to our customer support. 
   Please select language to proceed",
  "buttons": [
    {
      "text": "English",
      "value": "language_english",
      "type": "postback"
    },
    {
      "text": "Germany",
      "value": "language_germany",
      "type": "postback"
    }
  ]
}';
```

I have tried replacing the whitespaces and newline like this

```
$json = preg_replace("/\n/m", '\n', $json);
$what   = "\\x00-\\x19"; // all whitespace characters except space itself
$json = trim(preg_replace( "/[".$what."]+/" , '' , $json));
```

Which results into a string like this

```
\n{\n  "text": "Hi {{fname}} \n   Welcome to our customer support. \n   Please select language to proceed",\n  "buttons": [\n    {\n      "text": "English",\n      "value": "language_english",\n      "type": "postback"\n    },\n    {\n      "text": "Germany",\n      "value": "language_germany",\n      "type": "postback"\n    }\n  ]\n}
```

Notice the `\n` in between and outside double quotes which makes it an invalid json and hence json_decode won't work in this case.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you working with broken JSON in the first place?

Comment: This is not a valid json. json_decode can not decode something that is not json but looks like.

Comment: It works in *no* version of PHP: https://3v4l.org/Wq5L5

Comment: possible duplication of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "text": "Hi {{fname}} \n Welcome to our customer support. \n Please select language to proceed",
    "buttons": [{
            "text": "English",
            "value": "language_english",
            "type": "postback"
        },
        {
            "text": "Germany",
            "value": "language_germany",
            "type": "postback"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a valid json. i added line breaks so you can use them if you want to print the messages in browser.

You can use this nice [tool](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your json when you have doubts.

***Editing my answer based on comment feedback.***

First of all the right step is that you figure out why you have a broken json in the database. If it's not on you and you have to fix it in php then a solution could be like this:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$data = '
{
  "text": "Hi {{fname}} 
   Welcome to our customer support. 
   Please select language to proceed",
  "buttons": [
    {
      "text": "English",
      "value": "language_english",
      "type": "postback"
    },
    {
      "text": "Germany",
      "value": "language_germany",
      "type": "postback"
    }
  ]
}';


        if (strstr($data, "\n")) {
            $data = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '  ', $data));
        }

        echo $data;
```

Above code will capture the line breaks of your text field, and replace them with **DOUBLE** space. Then you will get a valid json like:

```
{
"text": "Hi {{fname}}  Welcome to our customer support.  Please select language to proceed",
"buttons": [
{
"text": "English",
"value": "language_english",
"type": "postback"
},
{
"text": "Germany",
"value": "language_germany",
"type": "postback"
}
]
}
```

What you can do if you need the line breaks is that you decode your json (just like you want and replace the double spacing in `text` field with a line break

Comment: Hi @pr1nc3 . The json string posted above comes from the database as is.

Comment: Then you should check why you have invalid JSON in your DB.

Comment: Edited my post. As i mention in my edited post this solution is suggested only if you can't fix your json so you retrieve it in a valid format.