# How to use OpenFeign to get a pojo array?

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson, netflix-feign

I’m trying to use a OpenFeign client to hit an API, get some JSON, and convert it to a POJO array.

Previously I was simply getting a string of JSON and using Gson to convert it to the array like so

```
FeignInterface {
    String get(Request req);
}
String json = feignClient.get(request);
POJO[] pojoArray = new Gson().fromJson(json, POJO[].class);
```

This was working. I would like to eliminate the extra step and have feign auto decode the JSON and return a POJO directly though, so I am trying this

```
FeignInterface {
    POJO[] get(Request req);
}
POJO[] pojoArray = feignClient.getJsonPojo(request);`
```

I am running into this error

`feign.codec.DecodeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $`

Both methods used the same builder

```
feignClient = Feign.builder()
     .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
     .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
     .target(FeignInterface.class, apiUrl);
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you share an example `JSON` payload? It looks like it is not sent as `JSON` but rather as `String` so it starts from `"` instead of `[` or `{`. Probably you need to register some kind of interceptor which will let you remove `"` from incoming payload. See [“Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1/28418787)

Comment: Why do you want an array specifically? It's more usual to use a `Collection` or `List`.

Comment: @chrylis I do convert it to a `List` afterwards, but regardless I don't understand why it isn't returning as an array

Comment: @MichałZiober 
[\r\n {\r\n "key": "value",\r\n etc etc

Comment: It does not look well. You can only have `new lines` in values. See [How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

Comment: Have you fixed your problem? What was the final way to fix it?

Comment: @MichałZiober your original comment about it being a `String` was correct. I implemented a new `feign.codec.Decoder` and using that I was able to make the Feign client return the json as a pojo array.

Comment: @shanjib_, great to hear that. If you think my answer was helpful, please, consider to read [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It will make clear for others that this is a way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have broken `JSON` payload. Before serialising you need to remove all unsupported characters. [`Feign`](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) allows this:

> If you need to pre-process the response before give it to the Decoder,
>   you can use the mapAndDecode builder method. An example use case is
>   dealing with an API that only serves jsonp, you will maybe need to
>   unwrap the jsonp before send it to the Json decoder of your choice:

```
public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonpApi jsonpApi = Feign.builder()
         .mapAndDecode((response, type) -> jsopUnwrap(response, type), new GsonDecoder())
         .target(FeignInterface.class, apiUrl);
  }
}
```

So, you need to do the same in your configuration and:

- `trim` response and remove all `whitespaces` at the beginning and end of payload.
- remove all `new_line` characters like: `\r\n`, `\r`, `\n`

Use [online tool](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to be sure your `JSON` payload is valid and ready to be deserialised .