# \n gives error when parsing json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a json array like this:

```
[
{
"variable1":"example",
"variable2": "example1\nexample2\nexample3"
},
{
"variable1":"exampleLast\n",
"variable2": "example1\nexample2\nexample3"
}
]
```

I am trying to parse this json a List in Flutter.

`List posts = json.decode(response.data);`

When I tried using 'dart:convert' it gives error `FormatException... Control character in string (at line...)`.

I found this issue on Github but I can not find solution.
https://github.com/dart-lang/convert/issues/10

Comment: Try using Gson       Gson gson = new Gson();
            Categoty _cate = gson.fromJson(jsonresponse, Categoty.class);

Comment: Replace \n with \\n.

Comment: This issue about Flutter not Java. There is no Gson library in flutter.

Comment: Hey, @EnisErkaya if you find my answer correct please mark it as correct. so others can use verified answers.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to replace **single slash** to **double slash** and everything goes fine.

`String replaced = string.replaceAll(r'\', r'\\');`

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the single backslash(\n) with double backslash(\\n) in your code:

```
[{
    "variable1": "example",
    "variable2": "example1\\nexample2\\nexample3"
},
{
    "variable1": "exampleLast\\n",
    "variable2": "example1\\nexample2\\nexample3"
}]
```

You need to escape the \ in your string (turning it into a double-), otherwise it will become a newline in the JSON source, not the JSON data.

Answer (score 3):

Previous answers didn't help me.
In the mentioned Github thread there is a good solution: add r to make compiler think that there is no special characters in the line.

```
final jsonContent = r'''{ "pageNumber": 0, "pageCount": 0, "transactionId": "126cf723-1d57-4f49-8fb2-072b7c23ec1e", "entries": [ { "content": "{\"resourceType\":\"Bundle\",\"id\":\"DRiefcase_2021-03-15__ManjoorKapoor_Pres-13116\",\"meta\":{\"versionId\":\"1\",\"lastUpdated\":\"2021-01-20T04:51:59.1497479Z\",\"profile\":[\"https:\\/\\/nrces.in\\/ndhm\\/fhir\\/r4\\/StructureDefinition\\/DocumentBundle\"]}}}]}''';
```

Answer (score 1):

And you can replace it like this

```
String replaced = string.replaceAll('\n', '\\n');
```

also check this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)