# Converting "\n" to an actual new line

Tags: c#, json, string

I'm creating a .json file from C# code using the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(User)` and `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` functions. One of the user attributes is "CONFIG" which is a long multi-line string that is fetched from a DataBase. When opening the new .json file, the "CONFIG" attribute is written on a one really long line with multiple "\n" symbols. How can I change it in order to actually see the string in a multi-line string?

I tried replacing all "\n" for "\n" but it did not change anything.
I also print the string on the console just before serializing it and it is printed on multiple lines.

How I want it to be :

```
...
{
   "USER":1,
   "SETTINGS": "SETT_1=YES
                SETT_2=YES
                SETT_3=YES"
}
...
```

How it is right now:

```
...
{
   "USER":1,
   "SETTINGS": "SETT_1=YES\nSETT_2=YES\nSETT_3=YES"
}
...
```

Comment: `"\n"` **is** an actual new line. In order to display it in your editor with line breaks, you will need to parse the string.

Comment: That string *does* contain a new line.  `\n` is a newline escape sequence.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline strings in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json)

Comment: Note that the JSON escape rules *require* the newline to be escaped as `\n` in the string; you cannot have an actual, unescaped newline in it (without breaking it, that is). Once parsed as a value, you can display it however you like. (You could also consider a more appropriate serialization format, where you split the actual settings into an object with properties.)

Comment: This I understand. But what could I do in order to actually see the new lines when I open a text editor with the resulting .json file? Thank you