# How to show new line character the view from a json file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the view I would like to show the character new line in the input value '/n'
If my json file like below:

> "NotesTwo": [
> {
> "Note": " Verification \n of income)"
> }
> ],

The character new line doesn't show.

I have tried to use @HTML.raw().

controller:

```
 public ActionResult Edit()
        {    
            var Response = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(JsonFileName));
            var _Loan = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Main>>(Response);

            return View(_Loan);
        }
```

View:

```
<input name="txtNoteOne_Note_@(conta7)" type="text" value="@Html.Raw(NotesOne.Note)"  />
```

Comment: Did you try to do a double backslash?

Comment: @anatp_123 - Try to double slash.
I have checked and it's working double slash.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslash with another backslash

```
"NotesTwo": [ { "Note": " Verification \\n of income)" } ],
```