# How to convert unicode string to JSON?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to convert below unicode string to JSON Object.

```
var str = '{"method_title":"Bank. Transfer","instructions":"Account Name: Sriram Me Co.,Ltd.\r\n----------------------------------------------\r\n- Furnin Commercial Bank\r\nAccount: 111-111-111\r\n----------------------------------------------\r\n- LIKSA Bank\r\nAccount: 111-111-111r\n----------------------------------------------\r\n\r\nAfter you have made bank transfer, please kindly visit \"PAYMENT\" to submit your payment detail."}';
```

below is the approach that I have followed

```
var myEscapedJSONString = decodeURIComponent(str);
console.log(JSON.parse(myEscapedJSONString));
```

and I am getting the below error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 82
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decodeURIComponent` is out of business here.

To use `JSON.parse`, the format must be correct.

So here, you must first remove line breaks with something like `.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")`.

Then the next problem is `"PAYMENT"`, double quote cannot appears here, so you can remove with `.replace(/"PAYMENT"/g, 'PAYMENT');`

```js
const str = '{"method_title":"Bank. Transfer","instructions":"Account Name: Sriram Me Co.,Ltd.\r\n----------------------------------------------\r\n- Furnin Commercial Bank\r\nAccount: 111-111-111\r\n----------------------------------------------\r\n- LIKSA Bank\r\nAccount: 111-111-111r\n----------------------------------------------\r\n\r\nAfter you have made bank transfer, please kindly visit \"PAYMENT\" to submit your payment detail."}';

const cleaned = str
  .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "")
  .replace(/"PAYMENT"/g, 'PAYMENT');

console.log(JSON.parse(cleaned));
```