# Resolve error 400 from request.json in Flask

Tags: python, flask

im having trouble forming a proper response using Flask.requests.json

```
@app.route("/slack/post", methods=["POST"])
def post_response_to_slack():
    try:
        body = request.json
```

the output using request.data is:

```
 b'{"phone":"+1XXXXXXXXX",\n"body":"This\nDoesn\'t\nWork",\n"slack_tag":"slack_bot"\n}'
```

when i try request.json i get `400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`

i suspect its something to do with incorrect handling of the new lines but im not sure where im going wrong

the header content type is `Content-Type: application/json`

for some more context without line breaks it works:

```
b'{"phone":"+1XXXXXXXX",\n"body":"This works ",\n"slack_tag":"slack_bot"\n}'
```

with request.json returning:

```
{'phone': '+1XXXXXXXXX', 'body': 'This works ', 'slack_tag': 'slack_bot'}
```

my guess is i need to change the `\n` into `\\n` but im not sure how to do that if its coming in as a request

relevant: [How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

Answer (score 0):

You're right. If you're using request.json it will try to put it into that format, and you can't just put \n between them, that's why you're getting the 400 error.
Can I ask why you need these line breaks?

Comment: the payload being parsed is from a texting application through Twilio, so if someone puts a line break in their text it throws an error currently. the only other way i can think of getting this info is parsing the ```request.data``` string

Comment: Good idea. Just parse it with request.data and handle the line breaks with some code.