# how can i add Line break in JSON?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is that I want to add a line break between

```
remoteMessage.notification.title + remoteMessage.notification.body
```

title and body

If I use my code screen view show like this

[image]

this is my code

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    Alert.alert(
      "A new FCM message arrived!",
      JSON.stringify(
        remoteMessage.notification.title + remoteMessage.notification.body
      )
    );
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

How can I fix my code? if I want to show like this?

```
title 
body
```

Comment: Use `title + '\n' + body`

Comment: What has this to do with [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)?

Comment: And why do you call `JSON.stringify()` on a string?

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json) ?

Comment: What you use for the line break depends on where the text is going to be displayed. The fact you're storing it in JSON beforehand is irrelevant

Comment: Do you really need those `""` around? Because that's what you get from `JSON.stringify()`, otherwise the line could be `Alert.alert(remoteMessage.notification.title+'<br>'+remoteMessage.notification.body);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\n`, otherwise, You can try with `<br/>` between two texts.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    Alert.alert(
      "A new FCM message arrived!",
      JSON.stringify(
        remoteMessage.notification.title +"<br/>"+ remoteMessage.notification.body
      )
    );
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Comment: if the \n is not work then Please add <br/> between texts.
title + "<br/>" + body

Comment: Rather than adding parts of answer in the comments, you can edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\n` and `white-space: pre-line;` [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

```js
const text = "Title\nBody"

function App() {
  return <div className="pre-line">{text}</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.pre-line {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use white-space: pre-wrap to include tab as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to handle CSS (I hope you are a front developer),
you can line break it with a combination of css' white-space: break-spaces and '\n'.

your.json file

```
{
   text: "I want to show you \nthe text that is line break."
}
```

your.css file

```
p {
   white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

Maybe it looks like this.

```
I want to show you
the text that is line break.
```