# Parsing error: Missing '}' or object member name in Google search console for seet.org

Tags: javascript, html, css, head

I have an issue in my head section and I put an image link for that so my whole website pages have the same issues on all pages.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="../img.dlwjdh.com/upload/8231/190925/favicon.svg" />
  <meta name="Copyright" content="All Rights Reserved btoe.cn" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title>Autoclave, West Arrangement Fabric Machine_Xi'anAutoclave_Xi'anPrepreg 
         equipment_Xi'anHydraulic pressure forming process Xi'an Impregnation Tank-Shaanxi 
         Shenying Equipment Technology Co., Ltd.-Shaanxi Shenying Equipment Technology Co., Ltd. 
  </title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="Xi'an arranging machine_Xi'an Autoclave equipment|Xi'an prepreg 
      equipment|Xi'an hot press molding process|Xi'an Impregnation Tank|Xi'an winding machine" 
    />
     <meta name="description" content="Xi'an autoclave looks for Shaanxi Shenying Equipment 
      Technology Co., Ltd., Shenying focuses on the research and development of composite 
      equipment and product production, and has a large-scale production base with strong strength 
      and rich experience. At the same time, it provides autoclave leasing or composite product 
      processing , Customers with needs in this regard are welcome to inquire!" />
   <link href="../css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/swiper-3.4.2.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/sm.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/common.css" />
   <script src="../linksubmit/push.js"></script><script src="../js/n/baidupush.js"></script>
   <script language="Javascript">  
   document.oncontextmenu=new Function("event.returnValue=false");  
   document.onselectstart=new Function("event.returnValue=false");  
   </script>
   <script src="../js/saohei/index.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/responcive.css" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user- 
  scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
  <script type="application/ld+json">{
  "@context":"https://ziyuan.baidu.com/contexts/cambrian.jsonld",
  "@id": "https://seet.org/autoclave/glass-autoclave.html",
  "appid":"no",
  "title":"Autoclave, West Arrangement Fabric Machine_Xi'anAutoclave_Xi'anPrepreg 
  equipment_Xi'anHydraulic pressure forming process Xi'an Impregnation Tank-Shaanxi Shenying 
  Equipment Technology Co., Ltd.-Shaanxi Shenying Equipment Technology Co., Ltd.",
  "description":"Xi'an autoclave looks for Shaanxi Shenying Equipment Technology Co., Ltd., 
  Shenying focuses on the research and development of composite equipment and product production, 
  and has a large-scale production base with strong strength and rich experience. At the same 
  time, it provides autoclave leasing or composite product processing , Customers with needs in 
  this regard are welcome to inquire!",
  "pubDate":"",
  } 
  </script>
   <script src="http://bdimg.share.baidu.com/static/api/js/share.js?v=89860593.js? 
   cdnversion=453143"></script>   <--here is problem-->
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Here it is whats' problem I have in this image so see it:

> Parsing error: Missing '}' or object member name

[image: here it is whats' problem I have in this image so see it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue is with the invalid JSON. This website (https://jsonlint.com/) can be used to validate the JSON.

Use the below one that I fixed and check once

```
{
    "@context": "https://ziyuan.baidu.com/contexts/cambrian.jsonld",
    "@id": "https://seet.org/autoclave/glass-autoclave.html",
    "appid": "no",
    "title": "Autoclave, West Arrangement Fabric Machine_Xi'anAutoclave_Xi'anPrepreg equipment_Xi'anHydraulic pressure forming process Xi'an Impregnation Tank-Shaanxi Shenying Equipment Technology Co., Ltd.-Shaanxi Shenying Equipment Technology Co., Ltd.",
    "description": "Xi'an autoclave looks for Shaanxi Shenying Equipment Technology Co., Ltd., Shenying focuses on the research and development of composite equipment and product production, and has a large-scale production base with strong strength and rich experience. At the same time, it provides autoclave leasing or composite product processing , Customers with needs in this regard are welcome to inquire!",
    "pubDate": ""
}
```

If you want to handle new lines in json then take a look here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66531090/11510551)

Comment: it nicely works but, I submitted fixes in the google search console but it not replacing this correction with a old one, sadly I have one more problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an SEO related issues, but try this.

Clear the js version to this

```
<script src="http://bdimg.share.baidu.com/static/api/js/share.js"></script>
```