# How to convert 'string of array objects' to an array in react?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, string, javascript-objects

I have researched a few questions on StackOverflow but couldn't find a relevant answer.

I have a **string of array** like this:

```
"[{"insert":"Test"},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"header":1}},{"insert":"Asdasfff"},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"list":"bullet"}},{"insert":"Asadsf"},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"list":"bullet"}},{"insert":"Sfsfsft"},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"header":2}},{"insert":"Make"},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"list":"unchecked"}},{"insert":"Back"},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"list":"checked"}},{"insert":"Ban"},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"list":"unchecked"}},{"insert":"Fg"},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"list":"checked"}}]"
```

and I need to convert it to an array as shown below:

[image: Desired Output Image]

I tried `JSON.parse()` but it didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the `\n` in your JSON. Here an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191059/11749096

```
function jsonEscape(str)  {
    return str.replace(/\n/g, "\\\\n").replace(/\r/g, "\\\\r").replace(/\t/g, "\\\\t");
}

var data = `[{"insert":"Test"},{"insert":"\n","attributes": 0}]`;
var dataObj = JSON.parse(jsonEscape(data));
console.log(dataObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not a string of array, the first and the last double quote must be one quote  in your case because when you stringify an array it works like this :

```js
const goo = [{"insert":"Test"},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"header":1}}]
```

to stringify it :

```js
JSON.stringify(goo)
'[{"insert":"Test"},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"header":1}}]'
```

in this case your parse  works like :

```js
JSON.parse(foo)
0: {insert: 'Test'}
1: {insert: '\n', attributes: {…}}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```