# How to parse string with break lines to object

Tags: javascript

Is there a possible way to parse a string with breaklines to an object using JSON.parse?

```js
const text = '{ "name": "Anne", "desc": "Hi,\nThis is me" }';
const obj = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON.

Comment: Is it a dynamic value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

Comment: I just noticed the duplicate (should definitely look more before answering!), but I do think this should be closed as a duplicate and *not* as caused by typos (so it can be a better sign-post for anyone who looks it up), as the typo is not affected by the question in the title ("How to parse break lines/new lines"),

Comment: I agree, these guys didnt look at it close enough @Ivar

Comment: @DanielW. Agreed, closing as a dupe would be better. The typo was referring to the comma instead of a colon and I missed the second missing backslash. That being said we usually don't really reopen questions to close them again for a different close reason. If everything went the right way, it wouldn't've had any answers and would be Roomba'd eventually anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here:

1. To answer your question, you simply need to escape the character like this:

```
"Hi,\\nThis is me"
```

2. For your code specifically, you also have another syntax error with a `,`, instead of a `:`:

```
    const text = '{ "name": "Anne", "desc": "Hi,\\nThis is me" }';
    const obj = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(obj);
```

output:

```
{
name: "Anne" ,
desc: "Hi, This is me"
}
```