# call setContents for Quill works but then cause an error

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly, quill

Please see this code for working with `Quilljs`:

```
window.InitialQuill = {
  createQuill: function (quillElement) {
    var options = {
      debug: 'info',
      modules: {
        toolbar: '#toolbar',
      },
      placeholder: 'write something...',
      readonly: false,
      theme: 'snow',
    };

    new Quill(quillElement, options);
  },
  getQuillContent: function (quillControl) {
    return JSON.stringify(quillControl.__quill.getContents());
  },
  getQuillText: function (quillControl) {
    return quillControl.__quill.getText();
  },
  getQuillHTML: function (quillControl) {
    return quillControl.__quill.root.innerHTML;
  },
  loadQuillContent: function (quillControl, quillContent) {
    // return quillControl.__quill.setContents(JSON.parse(quillContent), 'api');
    var ops = [
      { insert: 'Hello ' },
      { insert: 'World!', attributes: { bold: true } },
      { insert: '\n' },
    ];
    return quillControl.__quill.setContents(ops, 'api');
  },
};
```

I'm using the above code in blazor this way:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

@if(EditorEnabled)
{
<br>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GetText">Get Text</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GetHTML">Get HTML</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GetEditorContent">Get Content</button>

<br />

<div>
    @EditorContent
</div>
<div>
    @((MarkupString)@EditorHTMLContent)
</div>

<br />
<button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="SaveContent">Save Content</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="LoadContent">Load Content</button>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<div id="toolbar">
    <span class="ql-formats">
        <select class="ql-font">
            <option selected=""></option>
            <option value="serif"></option>
            <option value="tahoma"></option>
        </select>
        <select class="ql-size">
            <option value="small"></option>
            <option selected=""></option>
            <option value="large"></option>
            <option value="huge"></option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
        <button class="ql-bold"></button>
        <button class="ql-italic"></button>
        <button class="ql-undeline"></button>
        <button class="ql-strike"></button>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
        <select class="ql-color"></select>
        <select class="ql-background"></select>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
        <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
        <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
        <button class="ql-indent" value="-1"></button>
        <button class="ql-indent" value="+1"></button>
        <select class="ql-align">
            <option selected=""></option>
            <option value="center"></option>
            <option value="right"></option>
            <option value="justify"></option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
        <button class="ql-link"></button>
    </span>
</div>
}

<div @ref="@DivEditorElement"></div>

@code {
    private string strSavedContent = "";
    private ElementReference DivEditorElement;
    private string EditorContent;
    private string EditorHTMLContent;
    private bool EditorEnabled = true;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if(firstRender == true)
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("InitialQuill.createQuill", DivEditorElement);
    }
}

private async Task GetText()
{
    EditorHTMLContent = "";
    EditorContent = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("InitialQuill.getQuillText", DivEditorElement);
}

private async Task GetHTML()
{
    EditorContent = "";
    EditorHTMLContent = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("InitialQuill.getQuillHTML", DivEditorElement);
}

private async Task GetEditorContent()
{
    EditorHTMLContent = "";
    EditorContent = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("InitialQuill.getQuillContent", DivEditorElement);
}

private async Task SaveContent()
{
    strSavedContent = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("InitialQuill.getQuillContent", DivEditorElement);
}

    private async Task LoadContent()
{
    var QuillDelta = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("InitialQuill.loadQuillContent", DivEditorElement, strSavedContent);
}
}
```

All buttons work fine except `Load Content`. It works and specific text shows in the editor but after then it cause a problem.

> Unhandled exception rendering component: An exception occurred executing JS interop: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.. See InnerException for more details.
> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: An exception occurred executing JS interop: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.. See InnerException for more details.

I wrote the code this way:

```
quillControl.__quill.setContents(JSON.parse(quillContent), 'api');
```

but I got the same error. Where is my problem?

Comment: Could you output the value of the JSON to see why this conversion would throw an error? Could your '\n' be the cause of this? Maybe escape double?

Comment: Hey, do you feel okay with my edit to your code format in your question? You can revert my edit if it's not good in your opinion.

Comment: so you use JSON.parse to make object out of string and your error is object cannot be converted to string, maybe just ommit JSON.parse ?

Comment: @RemiCrystal Please see my first comment below the "Albert" answer.

Comment: @johnSmith Please see my first comment below the "Albert" answer.

Comment: When you get this type of problem, it is helpful to log the value on either side of the JSInterop call - so inside the JS: loadQuillContents you could `console.log` the results of `quillControl.__quill.setContents(ops, 'api')` and in C# LoadContent, change the call to `InvokeAsync<object>` and `Console.WriteLine(QuillDelta)` - also put a breakpoint and inspect QuillDelta to see what is being returned.

Answer (score 2):

If you're converting a string to JSON, make sure that some characters are [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json), otherwise the conversion will not work as expected.

Comment: As you see in my code: `strSavedContent = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("InitialQuill.getQuillContent", DivEditorElement);` I get content from `Quill` by it's function and then I want to show that value in editor. I bind whatever I get from `Quill` to `Quill`

Comment: @Arian it still does not mean that everything is escaped correctly. Putting output back as input again doesn't guarantee that it works. Can you update your code with the output?

Comment: Could you explain more, What type of change you consider?

Comment: As I wrote as a comment on your post before, I don't know what the output looks like. If you could update your code with the output (just `console.log(strSavedContent)`), I could tell where the error lies and how to handle that. Your title implies that the error is with quill but I think that it is more of a parsing error when you're trying to convert to a JSON object.

Comment: @Arian have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, didn't work

Comment: @Arian my suggestion was not a solution... It's for debugging what you're throwing into the Plugin...

Answer (score 0):

You've set the expected return type as a string and are passing a full JSON object (the delta) which is why you're getting the error.
So here are your options:

**If you want to return an object you can change the type to object.**

```
private async Task LoadContent()
{
    var QuillDelta = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<Object>("InitialQuill.loadQuillContent", DivEditorElement, strSavedContent);
}
```

**If you want to return a string from the client-side you need to adjust the return value to also be stringified.**

```
loadQuillContent: function (quillControl, quillContent) {
    // return quillControl.__quill.setContents(JSON.parse(quillContent), 'api');
    var ops = [
        { insert: 'Hello ' },
        { insert: 'World!', attributes: { bold: true } },
        { insert: '\n' },
    ];

    return JSON.stringify(quillControl.__quill.setContents(ops, 'api'));
}
```

**If you want to return the object and stringify it server-side you can do the following.**

```
private async Task LoadContent()
{
    var QuillDelta = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<Object>("InitialQuill.loadQuillContent", DivEditorElement, strSavedContent);
    //this is using the Json namespace '@using System.Text.Json'
    var stringFromObject= JsonSerializer.Serialize(QuillDelta);
}
```