# Validate and clean up JSON in Omnis Studio?

Tags: omnis-studio-8, omnis-studio-10

A correct JSON is

```
[{
    "user_id": 1,
    "user_name": "John Doe I"
}, {
    "user_id": 2,
    "user_name": "Jane Doe III"
}]
```

But if it contains some illegal characters it will not validate. Like this with a CR after Doe:

```
[{"user_id":1,"user_name":"John Doe 
I"},{"user_id":2,"user_name":"Jane Doe III"}]
```

My question is if there is a "clean up" function in Omnis Studio 8 where the output is a correct JSON?

**EDIT**

To replace or delete KNOWN characters is easy. The problem is that text copied from MS Word and the Web can contain UNKNOWN characters. So I am searching for a command like

`Calculate VALIDJSON as keepvalidchar(NOTVALIDJSON)`

Is there such a beast?

Answer (score 2):

according to this post [How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

if you want newlines in a text string, you need to escape the \n.   so \n in a the original json string should be valid replacement for a 'cr'.  eg.

```
[{"user_id":1,"user_name":"John Doe\nI"},{"user_id":2,"user_name":"Jane Doe III"}]
```

My read on this is that if you are pulling the data out of a database to send some place on the web, you might want to escape the newline to retain it in the text, rather than altering the JSON after the fact.   Of course, that depends on the purpose of the API call to the server receiving the json.

I guess the crux is

- if you want the json to reflect the original text content including special characters, you escape it
- if you don't, then you remove it.   I'd probably clean the original source since I might want to leave the json formatted and doing a replace of \n for blank .. might not have the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply looking for a

```
do replaceall(lcVar,kCR,'\n') Returns lcVar
```

function call?

Thus replacing the CR character with the escaped normal encoding of '\n'

I guess the other question is, are you creating the JSON to send, or receiving the JSON and trying to decode it?

If receiving, maybe OJSON.$formatjson() may help?

Comment: I create JSON and send to an APi. If the JSON file is not 100 percent valid, the API refuses to load. So it is both about validating AND correcting. And the characters may be "unknown"  (not only CR)

Comment: The data that you are using to generate the JSON, is completely in your control?

Comment: Yes I control the creation of the JSON, but the data behind the JSON may be full of characters that not is allowed. (CR,LF and TAB are the most common, but there may be other unknown "MS Word" characters)

Comment: Would the OW3.$excapeuritext() work in this situation? As in the control characters would be translated, not causing an error... but what about the receiving end?

Comment: I do not think OW3.$excapeuritext() will work as my intention is to delete control characters, CR etc. I want to remove them completely. Like replaceall() but with unknown garbage characters.