# quick question about JSON new line to javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Basically I have a JSON file and whenever I take it to my js application and print it to the console it never print a new line I have no Idea why

my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "71046",
    "question": "What is a cpu?",
    "answer": "Brain of the computer,  it has all the circuity needed to proccess input, store data  and output results.",
    "options": [""]
  },
  {
    "id": "63888",
    "question": "What can the proccessor perform?",
    "answer": "1) Basic arithmetic 2) Logic Control 3) Input/Output",
    "options": []
  },
  {
    "id": "5418",
    "question": "CPU principle components:",
    "answer": "1) ALU (Arithmetic Logic Unit)\n 2) Processor Register\\n 3) Control Unit",
    "options": []
  }
]
```

I tried many solution to parse print and others and didn't work which is weird

I went through this link in stackoverflow and didn't find solution: [How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json)

Here what happens when I stringify (the \n or \n doesn't take it to another line):
[image]

Comment: How the console prints strings with `\n` is up to the console.

Comment: But if I want to print a new line instead of \n what can I do?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(jsonDataWillBeHere, null,  2)`, do you want something like this?

Comment: well not really, so where if you see my last example the "answer it has \n and \\n and whenever I print the whole json folder it does print a new line

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you don't "print JSON", but "print a JS object"

Basically, what you would get if the console would be in a browser and not in nodejs is [image]

To print JSON as JSON you must convert it back to text with `JSON.stringify`

```
    JSON.stringify(
        {
            "id": "71046",
            "question": "What is a cpu?",
            "answer": "Brain of the computer,  it has all the circuity needed to proccess input, store data  and output results.",
            "options": [""]
        }
    ),
    /*replacer(advanced)*/
    undefined,
    /*indent as <string> of spaces <number>*/
    2
)
```

Comment: But even when I printed JSON as stringify it didn't print my \n or \\n in a new line

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot with that thing marked ? @omerbt

Comment: I just Edited the question @Dimava

Answer (score 0):

Each valid JSON is a valid JS

What you are trying to get is

```
let j = "multiline
string"
```

which is obviously invalid in JS or JSON

---

This is caused by JSON stringifying strings.

Stringified strings can't contain newline, JSON allows newlines

For example:

```
const str = `
- multiline
- string
`


const json = JSON.stringify(str)
//    expected = '" \n- multiline \n- string \n"' - no newli
const expected = '"\\n- multiline\\n- string\\n"'
console.log(json == expected)

console.log(json.includes('\n')) // false, does not contain newlines 

try {
  console.log(JSON.parse('"asi\nzxc"'))
} catch(err) {
  /**
   * Unexpected token 
   * in JSON at position 4 
   */
  console.log(err)
}

/**
 * {
 *   "json": "\"\\n- multiline\\n- string\\n\""
 * } 
 */
console.log({json})


JSON.stringify(str)
```